# How make a custom variable to get Payment ticket bank (Boleto in PT-BR) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-variable

How can I get a payment ticket link in Magento 2  and set this value in a "Custom Variable" to use in my emails Templates?
I know how to get a transaction and I think the ticket is a string inside "transaction object"

Ex:
$transactions = $this->transactions->create()->addOrderIdFilter($orderId);
$transaction->exampleGetTiketLink();

But I don't know how to define this in my custom variable in this dashboard.
[image]